# Объясните почему такое страное поведение при сохранении?

Tags: php, yii2

вот собственно код

```
$basePath='page/2016/10/';
$field='id_page';
$id=1;
$name='podborka_vecher_01.jpg,%, podborka_vecher_17.jpg'

public function baseSave($basePath,$field,$id,$name){
        $transliterator= new Translit();
        $bp = array();
        if(preg_match('/,%,/',$name)){
            $mathes=explode(',%,',$name);
            foreach ($mathes as $math){
                $bp[] = $basePath;
                $names=$transliterator->traranslitImg($math);
                $theImage= Image::findOne(['path'=>$basePath, 'name'=>$name ]);
                if(!isset($theImage)){
                    $this->path=$basePath;
                    $this->$field=$id;
                    $this->name=$names;
                    $this->insert();
                }
            }
        }else{
            $names=$transliterator->traranslitImg($name);
            $theImage= Image::findOne(['path'=>$basePath, 'name'=>$name ]);
            if(!isset($theImage)) {
                $this->path = $basePath;
                $this->$field = $id;
                $this->name = $names;
                $this->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

получаю следующую ошибку

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'path' doesn't have a default value
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `abh_image` (`name`) VALUES ('-podborka_vecher_17.jpg')
```

не понимаю куда делось работа с этим

```
$this->path=$basePath;
$this->$field=$id;
```

и почему работает только `$this->name=$names;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы не подскажите как это работает:

```
$this->$field = $id;
```

И почему у вас определён `basePath` а вы присваиваете к неизвестному `path`

```
$this->path = $basePath;
// должно быть судя логики
$this->basePath = $basePath;
```

И того отрабатывает только

```
$this->name = $names;
```

Comment: `$this->$field = $id` сюда приходит '$field' наименование поля модели в данном случае `'id_page'`  `$this->path` это поле модели вот они все `'id', 'id_gods', 'id_post', 'id_cat', 'id_page'  ,'path'  ,'name' ` но суть в том что при первой итерации `foreach` все работает, а во второй появляется такая ошибка